# PostCSS cli encountering max line length from stdin when interpreting sourcemap

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, postcss, npm-scripts

I've got a sass compilation setup as follows in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "sass": "node-sass sass/app.scss --source-map-root file://${PWD}/ --source-map-embed true",
    "postcss:autoprefixer": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 2 versions' --map",
    "css": "npm run sass -s | npm run postcss:autoprefixer -s | exorcist css/app.css.map > css/app.css"
  }
```

This has been running fine to create external sourcemaps for some time. However recently it's been failing with postcss throwing an unclosed comment error. The comment in question being the opening tag to the sourceMappingURL. The sourceMappingURL is being embedded by node-sass as a dataUri with the `--source-map-embed true` command, which is necessary for the source maps to work at all with this method as it seems node-sass won't write them to file if it is piping output to stdout.

I'm guessing the dataUri has got so long it's hitting some sort of max line length. Whether this limitation is in bash (I'm on Mac OSX), node.js or the postcss-cli I'm not sure? Is it something I can increase manually, or are there any other workarounds?

**Update:**
After some further research, the problem seems to stem from [read-file-stdin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-file-stdin) which is returning an incomplete file from process.stdin. I'm not too familiar with node streams, but `read-file-stdin` relies on `stream.pipe` to read the data and I believe uses [gather-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gather-stream) to collect the streams chunks together. However this isn't working. If I change the `css` script to the following: `npm run sass -s | test.js` where `test.js` is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const gather = require( 'gather-stream' );

process.stdin.pipe( gather( complete ) );

function complete ( err, data ) {
    console.log( data.toString( 'utf8' ) );
}
```

The console output is an incomplete file

Comment: OK, downvote comment is perhaps fair, although a little harsh. Please find updated question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a bug with node-sass, which is [now fixed](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1823)